# match.call() returns a function or a symbol, but symbols can't be used by do.call()

Tags: r

I want to do a recursive function call with modified arguments in R.

```
recursive_function_call <- function(call) {

    fun_call <- as.list(call) 
    fun <- fun_call[[1]]
    arguments <- fun_call[-1]

    ## Modify Arguments 
    arguments$drop_option <- NULL

    ## Call Function
    result <- do.call(what = fun, args = arguments)
    return(result)
}
recursive_function_call(match.call())
```

I want to call this function from an array of similar functions. If this gets called from a top-level function the variable `fun` will be of type `symbol`, while it gets on a lower level function call fun will be a `function`.

My problem is that `do.call()` fails when the function is a symbol, while for the arguments it's OK to be symbols.

My solution is to convert the symbol to a string.

```
if (is.symbol(fun_call[[1]])) fun <- as.character(fun_call[[1]]) else fun <- fun_call[[1]]
```

1. Is there a better way to get the function of a call object?
2. Is there a way to check the symbol will be available after I converted it into a string? Or can I avoid the conversion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you’ve noticed, `do.call` constructs and invokes a call expression (and invokes it) from a function name (or function) and a list of arguments. But you already *have* a call expression, no need for `do.call` — so you can directly invoke it using `eval` or `eval.parent`:

```
recursive_function_call = function(call) {
    call$drop_options = NULL
    eval.parent(call)
}

recursive_function_call(match.call())
```

That said, I’m not sure what your function’s purpose is. Are you looking for [`Recall`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/Recall)?

Alternatively, you can use [`as.call`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/call.html) to coerce a list into a function call expression. And, once again, `eval` then evaluates it:

```
eval.parent(as.call(fun_cal))
```

— in fact, `as.call` is essentially the inverse of `as.list` on a call expression: `identical(as.call(as.list(call)), call)` is `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks. With your help I now also found it in the language definition. https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Manipulation-of-function-calls